# Is there a way to determine polarity of a DC device that has missing power adapter?

Tags: power-supply, polarity

Let's say someone has bench power supply and a multimeter, then is it possible in safe manner without damaging device to use these tools to determine devices polarity?

Update#1:
In this specific case it is braun shaver. I was able to find aftermarket charger but as can be seen plug has both terminals as equals (opposed to ones where usually plus is in middle and minus around it).

[image]

Comment: A screwdriver and/or spudger might be more suitable tools so that you can get a look inside.

Comment: What is the device? For some devices, determining the polarity with a power supply and/or multi-meter is straightforward. For others not so much.

Comment: If not printed on the label, take it apart. If it’s ultrasonic welded, assume positive on center pin.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy It is Braun shaver. Added picture of after market charger but I don't think label on it indicates there which is + and which -.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this](https://toothbrushbattery.com/blog/charging-toothbrush-from-12v-dc-charger/) website is a photo of a Braun charger cord that purports to show the polarity.

[image]

Might be correct. **Note that it's for a Braun toothbrush, not a shaver.**

Maybe start the power supply off slowly from zero with current limit set to something reasonable.

Edit: Here (from Amazon.ca) is an adapter that claims to be for some Braun models of shaver:

[image]

Polarity markings are similar even though the plug is a bit different.

And another shaver adapter from [Amazon.ca](https://www.amazon.ca/BENSN-Multigroom-Precision-Bodygroom-Sensotouch/dp/B081H7DDZX?ref_=ast_sto_dp):

[image]

All three of these are consistent, but you're still taking a bit of a risk connecting it.